# How add Header for first page table of contents?

Tags: table-of-contents

How add Header for first page table of contents, List of Figures and List of tabls?

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{book}
%%%%%%%%%%%%Tikz%%%%
\usepackage[left=2cm,right=2cm,top=3.25cm,bottom=3cm]{geometry}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{%
\markboth{#1}{}}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{%
\markright{\thesection\ #1}}
\fancyhf{} % delete current header and footer
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\bfseries\thepage}
\fancyhead[LO]{\bfseries\rightmark}
\fancyhead[RE]{\bfseries\leftmark}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.5pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
\addtolength{\headheight}{0.5pt} % space for the rule
\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
\fancyhead{} % get rid of headers on plain pages
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt} % and the line
}
    \renewcommand{\theequation}{\arabic{equation}}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
\listoftables

\chapter{Cha}

\section{Sec}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Aren't the chapter heads enough to remind you that you're at the beginning of the table of contents, list of figures, &c.? You also might mention the table of contents in the table of contents ;o)

Comment: The header needs to be inserted on the first page of the contants and the Figures and chapters.

Comment: But normally, the  `plain` page style is used for the 1st page of a chapter. A header is not  placed with a decorative aim, but an informative aim. This information is redundant on the first page.

Comment: I know. But it is necessary.

Comment: In this case, using `\thispagestyle{your page style}` just after `\tableofcontents` should work.

Comment: thank you very much.

Comment: You're welcome (but I don't approve!).

Comment: Me too. Does not have a general code?

Comment: I'm sorry, I forgot you use fancyhdr. Try writing `thispagestyle{fancy}`.

Comment: @Bernard  `\tableofcontents\thispagestyle{fancy}` affects only the *last* TOC page. So if the TOC has at least two pages, the first page still uses page style `plain`.

Answer (score 2):

The ToC etc., and `\chapter` use the `plain` pagestyle by default. To get what you want you need to change this to your `fancy` pagestyle for the ToC etc., but then for `\chapter` need to revert the `plain` style back to its original definition (unless of course you want headers on your `\chapter` pages, which I dislike. Here is a revised version of your MWE which caters for multipage ToCs.

```
% tocheaderprob.tex  SE 560800

\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{book}
%%%%%%%%%%%%Tikz%%%%
\usepackage[left=2cm,right=2cm,top=3.25cm,bottom=3cm]{geometry}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{%
\markboth{#1}{}}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{%
\markright{\thesection\ #1}}
\fancyhf{} % delete current header and footer
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\bfseries\thepage}
\fancyhead[LO]{\bfseries\rightmark}
\fancyhead[RE]{\bfseries\leftmark}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.5pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
\addtolength{\headheight}{0.5pt} % space for the rule
\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
\fancyhead{} % get rid of headers on plain pages
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt} % and the line
}
    \renewcommand{\theequation}{\arabic{equation}}

\usepackage{comment}

\makeatletter
\let\ps@originplain\ps@plain % save definition of plain pagestyle
\makeatother

\addtolength{\textheight}{-0.6\textheight} % short pages

\begin{document}

\fancypagestyle{plain}{} % change plain pagestyle to fancy

\tableofcontents 

\listoffigures 

\listoftables
\clearpage  % make sure LoT typesetting is finished

\makeatletter
\let\ps@plain\ps@originplain % revert plain style to the original
\makeatother

% lots of chapters for a multi-page ToC 
\chapter{Cha}
Text

\section{Sec}
Text

\subsection{Subsec}
Text

\chapter{Cha}
Text

\section{Sec}
Text

\subsection{Subsec}
Text

\chapter{Cha}
Text

\section{Sec}
Text

\subsection{Subsec}
Text

\chapter{Cha}
Text

\section{Sec}
Text

\subsection{Subsec}
Text

\end{document}
```